# Unable to access "encrypted.google.com" with "proxy.googlezip.net"

Tags: encryption, privacy, proxy, google

I [use](https://superuser.com/q/945924) Google data compression proxy with Firefox ([Abrowser 38](http://packages.trisquel.info/belenos-updates/abrowser)). Most websites are loaded without any problem but unable to access **encrypted.google.com**

[image: screen-shot]

So, is this is normal? i.e I've to use system (or no) proxy to use encrypted.google.com . Or can it be fixed? And why I am unable to load encrypted.google.com with proxy.googlezip.net:80?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can no longer be reproduced. The encrypted.google.com site no longer exists.

Comment: @forest Right. I want to self vote for closing but don't find option.

Comment: @forest Reported on [meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3181/94977)